# Scrolling in Sticky Notes

Tags: wpf, scroll, pdfnet

I got the following sticky note example:

[image]

If the sticky note has more than 9 rows, the additional rows are not visible.
I'm able to navigate through the note with my arrow keys. If I'm going to scroll with the mouse wheel, it seems to ignore the popup and just changes the page.

Is it possible to activate scrolling for sticky note popups?

Comment: Are you using PDFViewCtrl or PDFViewWPF class for viewing?

Comment: I'm using PDFViewWPF.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, we are looking into this now, and will update you shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Edit**:The solution outlined below will soon be available as part of the samples included in the PDFTron SDK download. In the meanwhile, I hope that the below solution helps.

Yes, it is possible to activate scrolling for sticky notes.

The problem is most apparent when using the single page view. It appears to work as expected in continuous mode.

However it is not as simple as setting `VerticalScrollVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;`. There are a few files that need to be modified to get this working.

The good news is that we can get the expected behaviour by modifying the code in the provided samples.

#### Solution

The solution is to add some handling for the `PreviewMouseWheel` event coming from the `PDFViewWPF` class.
In the downloaded samples, the following changes were made to get things running as expected:

- Add a method to handle the PreviewMouseWheel event in the `NoteHost` class (Samples/PDFViewWPFTools/CS/Utilities/NoteHost.cs)

  ```
  internal void HandlePreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
  {
      var originalSource = (UIElement)e.OriginalSource;
      if (originalSource.IsDescendantOf(mNoteBorder) && mTextBox.IsFocused)
      {
          mTextBox.ScrollToVerticalOffset(mTextBox.VerticalOffset - e.Delta);
          e.Handled = true;
      }
  }
  ```
- Also make sure to add `mTextBox.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;` in the `NoteHost.CreateNoteAndArrow()` method, after the `mTextBox` object is instantiated (~line 183).
- Next, edit the `NoteManager` class - Samples/PDFViewWPFTools/CS/Utilities/NoteManager.cs - and add a `HandlePreviewMouseWheel` method. This will internally call the `HandlePreviewMouseWheel` on each displayed (opened) note and break at the first one where the event gets handled.

  ```
  internal void HandlePreviewMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
  {
      foreach(var note in mActiveNotes)
      {
          note.Value.HandlePreviewMouseWheel(sender, e);
          if(e.Handled)
          {
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Next, edit the `ToolManager` class to ensure that the note manager gets a chance to handle the `PreviewMouseWheel` before attempting a page change. Open Samples/PDFViewWPFTools/CS/ToolManager.cs and navigate to the `PDFView_PreviewMouseWheel`. The existing method should look like this:

  ```
  private void PDFView_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
  {
      if (mCurrentTool != null && _IsEnabled)
      {
          ToolManager.ToolType prev_tm = mCurrentTool.ToolMode;
          ToolManager.ToolType next_tm;
          while (true)
          {
              mCurrentTool.PreviewMouseWheelHandler(sender, e);
              next_tm = mCurrentTool.NextToolMode;
              if (prev_tm != next_tm)
              {
                  mCurrentTool = CreateTool(next_tm, mCurrentTool);
                  prev_tm = next_tm;
              }
              else
              {
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  Replace it with the below code:

  ```
  private void PDFView_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
  {
      if (mCurrentTool != null && _IsEnabled)
      {
          ToolManager.ToolType prev_tm = mCurrentTool.ToolMode;
          ToolManager.ToolType next_tm;
          while (true)
          {
              mNoteManager.HandlePreviewMouseWheel(sender, e);
              if (!e.Handled)
              {
                  mCurrentTool.PreviewMouseWheelHandler(sender, e);
                  next_tm = mCurrentTool.NextToolMode;
                  if (prev_tm != next_tm)
                  {
                      mCurrentTool = CreateTool(next_tm, mCurrentTool);
                      prev_tm = next_tm;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      break;
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

By doing the above, we are giving the `NoteManager` a chance to handle the `PreviewMouseWheel` before doing anything else with it.

Another point to note is that we have to now **"do the scrolling"** in code, using the `mTextBox.ScrollToVerticalOffset` method in the `NoteHost` class.

Comment: Works perfectly just like I expected. Thank you very much!